# Certain libraries cause Tomcat to fail to deploy

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm just learning Tomcat, and have successfully deployed a simple test WAR to a Tomcat server.
However, when I attempt to add a library via Maven, Tomcat's JarScanner then fails to load the class files for my program, saying it can't find anything

```java
09-Feb-2020 05:36:42.568 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/webapps/api.war]
09-Feb-2020 05:36:42.668 FINE [http-nio-80-exec-8] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
09-Feb-2020 05:36:42.686 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/webapps/api.war] has finished in [117] ms
```

However, if I remove the library from pom.xml (and hence from the WAR), it loads fine.
Here are the libraries being loaded:

- JDA
- Trove4J
- jsr305
- opus-java
- opus-java-natives
- opus-java-api
- jna
- annotations
- okhttp
- commons-collections4
- nv-websocket-client
- slf4j-api
- jackson-databind
- jackson-annotations
- jackson-core

Further, I've already tried telling the JARScanner to not scan any JAR files, both in context.xml and in catalina.properties.

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=\
*.jar
```

```xml
<JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllDirectories="false" scanManifest="false" scanAllFiles="false"/>
```

Neither of these have resulted in the deployment working.
If I don't exclude the main library (JDA), then Tomcat reports an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.
The server is running Tomcat 9 on JDK 8, as is my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

From your log snippet - it doesn't seem that the WAR wasn't deployed, actually it was (see the third line): `Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/webapps/api.war] has finished in [117] ms`

Try to compare this output with the output from the WAR that you think "is deployed" and the chances are that you'll see the same message (I don't have a tomcat right now to verify this on my machine, but that's my assumption).

The second line: `No TLD files were found in resource path...` basically means that there are no TLD files in the WAR which of course doesn't mean that the war has errors...

TLD stands for Tag Library Descriptor - its for JSP tags which are not a mandatory component in Web Archives.

[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html) some information about TLDs

Comment: Here's catalina.out if I remove JDA from pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/hwQvPDqQ.
The fact that it correctly finds my Class file when I remove the dependency from Maven's pom file is what makes me thing it's the library.

Comment: Yes, if you remove JDA - it clearly deploys. How does the log look with JDA actually? can you add the full log like this?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/PU26q7Q6) you go. Nearly same output as from the question post. Just added JDA back, recompiled, and uploaded to Tomcat.

Comment: Both snippets have line: `org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat- 9.0.30/webapps/api.war] has finished in [XXX] ms` which means that in both cases the WAR is deployed in tomcat (there is a manager application in tomcat where you can view all the deployed WARs) - however internally the WAR might be different. It all depends on what does it do... Again, From the tomcat's standpoint in both cases the WAR is technically OK and its deployed...

Comment: Ended up figuring out the issue, just putting the fix here.
Either JDA or one of its libraries was compiled for a higher version of Java than the version of Jersey Servlet I was using was (My guess, Java 8 vs Java 7), resulting in an ArrayIndexOOB exception when it hit lambda methods.

Upgrading Jersey Servlet to a newer version resolved the issue.